# I am unable to call a funtcion from one file to another, eventhough both the files are in same workspace

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

File_1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int value;
    value = increment();
    value = increment();
    value = increment();

    printf("%d", value);
    return 0;
}
```

File_2.c:

```
static int var;
int increment()
{
    var = var+1;
    return var;
}
```

I was trying to execute File_1.c,

But the below error I am getting
implicit declaration of function 'increment' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
value = increment();

I am trying in Visual Studio Code.
Both the files are in same workspace.

Do I need to do something in vscode for that since I am able to get output in code blocks ?

Comment: Declare the function before main.

Comment: "Workspace" is a construct of your IDE.  It has no significance to the C code you are working with inside.